# Find analytic surjective map $f$ s.t. $(G_1,f)$ becomes a covering space of $G_2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G_1, G_2, \Omega$ be open connected sets in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $(G_1,f_1), (G_2,f_2)$ be covering spaces of $\Omega$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are analytic.

Show that if $G_1$ is simple connected, then there is an analytic map $f$ from $G_1$ to $G_2$ s.t. $(G_1,f)$ is a covering space of $G_2$.

I couldn't find a suitable $f$. Because I don't know how to make it surjective and analytic.

I have thought of choosing $f=f_1 \circ {f_2}^{-1}$, but it doesn't work. For each $\omega \in \Omega$, there is a neighborhood $\Delta$ s.t. for each component $C$ of $f_2^{-1}(\Delta)$, we have $f_2: C \rightarrow \Delta$ is a homeomorphism, so if I try to invert $f_2$, I need to choose the component, so some components are not reached by $f$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of topological spaces and continuous maps this is a [standard fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers) about covering spaces. *Locally* you have, speaking very informally, $f=f_2^{-1}\circ f_1$. Of course $f_2$ is not invertible, but it has local inverses near each point. The fact that $f$ is analytic now follows for free.

Comment: Umm could you explain a little bit how analytic function got local analytic inverse at each point?

Comment: @k99731 Do you know the definition of "analytic covering map"?

Comment: Oh I forgot the definition of a covering map gives a homeomorphism. I think I got it now. Thanks.